# XCode 4, ParseKit and Archive Target

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, parsekit

I'm trying to archive an iPad application that used ParseKit.  I'm able to run the app fine, utilizing ParseKit, for any build using the Debug Configuration (ie, Run on device / simulator ana analyze.)  When I use the Release Configuration, however, I get the following linker error:

ld: library not found for -lparsekit
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: I managed to fix this by finding parsekit.a in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos and copying to /usr/lib (one of the library path's in the Library Search Paths) in the Xcode project.  Obviously suboptimal, but it seems to have worked.

Comment: Sorry, i also renamed parsekit.a to libparsekit.a

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The fix for me was to select:

```
ParseKit.xcodeproj (subproject within my project)
-> Target: ParseKitMobile
-> Build Settings
-> Product Name
```

...and change the name from 'parsekit' to 'libparsekit'. Curious that this is necessary for XCode4, but it's now working for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

Check your flags in your release target: your debug and release builds will probably have different compiler flags set. In XCode4, go into your target's build settings and look for the "Other Linker Flags" section. You will hopefully find your release linker flags don't have a '-lparsekit' flag.

Comment: Hmm, the debug and release flags arethe same for both Debug and Release: "-ObjC -all_load"